# Stop jQuery counterUp Plugin Script from Reloading

Tags: jquery, counter, page-refresh

I'm using a simple counterUp script but when the columns of the website resize via media queries it is triggered again. Could anyone advise on the best way to run this and have it function just once without being retriggered unless the page is refreshed? Thanks!

```
<h3><span class="counter">457</span></h3>

$(document).ready(function() { //when document is ready
        $('.counter').counterUp({
            delay: 10,
            time: 1800
        });
    });
```

Fixed counterUp issue with the following:

```
$( window ).resize(function() { //Prevent being triggered again with window resize
        $('.counter').destroy();

    });
```

Solved! :)

Comment: Please post counterUp and make a [mcve] - there is nothing showing something that would retrigger anything

Comment: Not much information on how the CounterUp jQuery plugin works is there on its Github repo - your better option would be to use https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2 and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just added the following to prevent it from triggering again on resize:                                                                                                   $( window ).resize(function() {
        $('.counter').destroy();
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed counterUp issue with the following:

```
$( window ).resize(function() { //Prevent being triggered again with window resize
        $('.counter').destroy();

    });
```

Solved! :)